# Video lags behind sound on YouTube and other sources

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, video, performance

I'm using 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04.3 and SeaMonkey 2.53.5.1 -- but this problem has persisted from Ubuntu 14.04 and various updates of SeaMonkey for several years.  Unlike other questions I've seen about YouTube and other video, I don't have choppy sound or video; at least at my usual "middle size" setting, my video and audio play smoothly unless I have a network issue.  The problem is, the video *lags* behind the audio by around a quarter second -- that is, if someone on screen is talking, their voice will stop at the end of a statement, but their lips will continue to move for a fraction.

This happens with Firefox (kept up to date via automatic updates) as well, and with streaming video sources other than YouTube (tested just now on DailyMotion).

I have an nVidia GTx750 with 1 GB VRAM in PCI Express x16 slot, 16 GB system RAM, AMD FX8350 (8 cores, 8 threads, up to 4.1 GHz), and my primary system storage is on partitioned 250 GB SSD (which I've had for several years -- but this problem predates its installation), .  I'm using the proprietary nVidia driver, version 384.130 (very open to updating this from repo or from the nVidia site), but this has persisted over many driver upgrades and hardware upgrades over the years.

How can I get rid of this annoying video/audio sync problem?

Comment: 16.04 is eol on april 30th 2021 thats just around the corner you should reinstall with 20.04. now for your driver it is very out of date version 455 is the latest driver for your card(note 455 is in the 20.04 repo so you should be able to install with command "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall" or through gui in additional drivers

Comment: Does 20.04 have lag-free video on nVidia drivers?  I ask because I've had this problem for a long time...

Comment: Also, why is it that for a fresh release, the answer is "wait for the dot release update" and for one that's had that, it's "install the next version"?  Yeah, I know, separate question -- which will be closed as opinion based or otherwise "unanswerable".  Guess I'll have to spend one of my upcoming two 4-day weekends installing Ubuntu instead of working in darkroom, as I'd prefer.

Comment: the suggestion to update is for reasons of os support it may or may not help the lag but it's good practice to keep your os up to date. now lets see if changing your driver helps here is NVIDIA driver ppa instuctions (https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_nvidia_ppa/) please use  to update your driver and check if the problem persists

Comment: another thing to consider is your hardware bottleneck (https://pc-builds.com/calculator/FX-8350_Eight-Core/GeForce_GTX_750/0sI0Jz8A/16/100/)

Comment: Okay, so I'll rebuild my computer and install the latest/greatest OS, and go off reservation to get an unvetted video driver.  May as well run Windows.  If the solution for a specific, limited performance problem is "spend $500 and a long weekend" maybe I should just buy a new iPad.  It's evil Apple, but it'll outperform any desktop hardware I can afford.

Comment: the driver is vetted I did say it's in the repo for later os such as 20.04 furthermore as ubuntu wont vet the driver for an os that is soon to be EOL you can either go to nvidia site and get the driver and install it the hard way or you can use a ppa and install it the easy way. also you said this problem has persisted sense 14.04 which likely means this is a hardware problem and as shown your hardware configuration has a bottleneck and there is no need to completely rebuild your pc to fix bottleneck just get another gpu or down clock your cpu

Comment: Wait -- slowing down my CPU will improve performance?  I must be on the wrong drugs.

Comment: reducing your cpu clock to 85% (so 3.485 ghz) will decrease your bottleneck by 2% (https://pc-builds.com/calculator/FX-8350_Eight-Core/GeForce_GTX_750/0sI0Jz6E/16/100/)  still over 10% at 14.32% but better than 16.12%

Comment: That makes no sense.  Also, I'm not running YouTube in full screen; it's in the larger of the windowed modes (full screen is much worse).

Comment: I'm thinking of it like this if your cpu is handling your sound and your gpu is handling your video and you have to much of a bottleneck then one may happen slightly faster then the other.

Comment: So, buying the fastest CPU and fastest GPU I could afford was my mistake?  Should have bought just enough CPU to keep up with the GPU?  This stuff is silly.

Comment: @wraith3690001 I tried setting my max CPU clocks down as far as 2.1 GHz, and the video still lagged the audio on YouTube.  I just added the nVidia ppa and followed their process to check for newer drivers -- 384 (which I'm running already) and 340 are the only choices.  Looks like another question for which the answer is "upgrade your Ubuntu".  Guess I know what I'll be doing over Xmas or New Year's weekend...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found at least a temporary solution to this while digging through my nVidia Settings application for clues.

At one point, in `GPU0 - (GeForce GTX 750)`, I noticed a display of GPU Utilization -- standing solid at 100% while I was looking at an article with a few static images and ads blocked.  What could be running my GPU at 100%, and could it be the cause of my video lag?  One thing, in my case: Einstein@Home, a BOINC computing task that I have set to use GPU only (so it can coexist with MilkyWay@Home, running on my 8 CPU cores).  Checking my BOINC manager settings, I found I had BOINC set to stop computing "when computer is in use (any core above 25%)" -- but GPU wasn't set to shut down in the same circumstances.

I checked the box for GPU computing to shut down when computer is in use, popped up a YouTube video to check it -- and sure enough, my video and audio are now in sync, at least within the limits of my eye and ear.

I do plan to reinstall Linux on my system over the next couple weekends, but I'm seriously considering whether I want to continue with a system that both lags significantly behind current software development *and* requires me to reinstall every couple years (because the first thing an "upgrade" does is delete all my added repositories and ppa sources) -- or switch to a rolling distro based on Debian.